# puppeteerのscreenshotで保存したjpegファイルが開けない

Tags: javascript, windows, 画像, puppeteer, photoshop

node.jsでpuppeteerを動かしています。

下記のようなコードでGoogleのトップページへアクセスし、スクリーンショットをjpgファイルとして保存しました。

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

const page = await browser.newPage();
const url = 'https://www.google.com';
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
await page.screenshot({ type: 'jpeg', path: 'ss.jpg' });
```

保存したファイルを
Windows8.1のPC上でダブルクリックすると
Windowsフォトビューアーが起動しますが
「この画像をWindows フォトビューアーで表示できません。利用できる十分なメモリがない可能性があります。」
のようなエラーになります。

ss.jpgよりもファイルサイズが大きい別のファイル（puppeteerで作成したものではない）は開けるので、メモリうんぬんのエラーメッセージは該当しないと判断しています。

また、スライドショーでss.jpgを開いたときは画像が表示できます。
Chromeのブラウザにss.jpgをドラッグ＆ドロップした場合も画像が表示されます。

jpgファイルとして成立はしているけれど、特定のソフト（Windowsフォトビューアー）でだけ開けないという状況だと思われます。

await page.screenshot({ type: 'jpeg', path: 'ss.jpg' });
の部分を
await page.screenshot({ type: 'png', path: 'ss.png' });
にした場合は
Windowsフォトビューアーでもss.pngが開けます。

'https://www.google.com'
以外のURLでスクリーンショットを撮った場合も同様の現象です。

jpg保存すると、画像が表示されない。
png保存すると、画像が表示される。
jpgもスライドショーやブラウザでは画像が表示される。

puppeteerで保存した画像以外のjpgは特に問題無く表示されるので、puppeteer側での問題だと認識しています。

特定のソフトでだけjpgファイルが開けない現象について、心当たりがあればご教示ください。

いまのところ、
・jpeg自体にバージョンとかコーデックみたいなものがあるのでは？
・puppeteerやWindowsフォトビューアーで扱えるjpegのバージョンは？
みたいな想定で調べている最中です。

[image: ss.jpg]

Comment: 参考までに、画像のファイルサイズや解像度の情報もあると回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: ファイルサイズは22.9 KB (23,502 バイト)
解像度は横710、縦1000です。

質問に該当の画像ss.jpgを添付しました。
stackoverflowにアップロードしたファイル、ダウンロードして開いてみると同じ現象が発生します。

Comment: Windows10のフォトだと問題無く開けるようです。もしかしたらWindows8.1からWindows10の最新版までの間にプログラム/ライブラリ/OSいずれかの機能/対応強化があったのかもしれませんね。ただ、「フォト」と「フォトビューアー」は違うプログラムのようで、Windows10でのこんな記事があるようです。[【対策】フォトビューアーで画像が表示されない｜メモリー不足？｜Win10](https://yoshitechblog.com/cant-display-images-countermeasure-photo-viewer)

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。
ご紹介いただいたリンクと同じく、スライドショーやペイントならば画像が表示できます。

Answer (score 0):

半分解決したので自己回答。

下記リンクを参考にICC_PROFILEをICC_PROFILXに書き換え。
Windowsフォトビューアーでss.jpgが開けるようになりました。
https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/windows-photo-viewer-can%E2%80%99t-display-this-picture-because-there-might-not-be-enough-memory-available-on-your-computer.4075896/

具体的な手順
・Visual Studio CodeにHex Editorというプラグインをインストール
・Visual Studio Codeでss.jpgを右クリック　＞　Open With　＞　Hex Editor
・Hex Editorで開いたss.jpgからICC_PROFILEの文字を見つけICC_PROFILEXに書き換え（EをXに書き換え）

ICC_PROFILEというのがあると、Windowsフォトビューアーでファイルが開けないみたいです。

ここは一旦閉じて、puppeteerの質問としてではなく
「javascriptとICC_PROFILE」の視点で別途質問をあげようかと思います。